# Distribution with many cumulants vanishing

Tags: probability-distributions, cumulants

Let $X$ be a random variable. It is well-known that $X$ is normally distributed if and only if its last cumulants $\kappa_3 = \kappa_4 = ... = 0$ vanish. I was wondering if there are standard distributions satisfying $\kappa_m = ... = \kappa_n = 0$ for arbitrary $m<n\le\infty$, especially for $m=3$.

Comment: Any symmetric distribution will have $\kappa_3=0$.

Comment: That's true. What about higher moments vanishing?

Comment: By standard distributions do you mean to enumerate and discuss common distributions instead of constructing one?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Yes, a common distribution would be nice as those are the ones people care more about. Nevertheless, a constructed one would be a starting point.

Comment: @Marcel Then [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Cumulants_of_some_discrete_probability_distributions) already lists cumulants of quite some common distributions.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco True, but those don't satisfy the above property that some of them are vanishing.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Well, then think of what I call common in a more general way. Wiki only mentions very few distributions; there are much more distributions out there which are studied and which I am probably not be aware of. Sorry for the confusion. And as I said, a constructed one would be a starting point at least.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no: the Normal distribution is the only one with a finite polynomial as cumulant generating function.  See http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Cumulants#Uniqueness

The proof is credited to Marcinkiewicz (1939).
Marcinkiewicz, Math Z (1939) 44: 612. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01210677

Edit: I read the post a bit too quickly; this applies to $n=\infty$, not the case when $n$ is finite.